# Distance between Brownian Motion and scaled Gaussian random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm currently reading this paper: http://user.math.uzh.ch/barbour/pub/Barbour/SteinDiffusion.pdf and in equation (2.26) the author uses the following fact:

If $Z(t)$ is a standard Brownian Motion and $Z_n(t)=n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor nt\rfloor}X_k$ for $X_k$ iid. standard normal then $Z(t)$ and $Z_n(t)$ can be realised together by first realising $Z(t)$ and then defining $Z_n(j/n)=Z(j/n)$, which then can be used to prove that:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|Z_n(t)-Z(t)|\right]\leq Cn^{-1/2}\sqrt{\log n}$$
for some constant $C$.

Does anyone know how this last claim can actually be proved?

Comment: Yes. What did you try?

Comment: Obviously $Z_n$ stays constant on intervals $[j/n,(j+1)/n)$ so I've been trying to use some properties of the running supremum of Brownian Motion. Doob's inequalities combined with Jensen's inequality can be used to obtain some bound on $\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t\in[0,1/n)}|Z(t)|\right]$ but this is still not quite what we're looking for... Unfortunately, I'm not very confident with coupling arguments yet but I realise that this might also be the way to go... However, I haven't found any good reference for dealing with this particular case yet.

Comment: If anyone's interested, this follows by writing the LHS as:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|Z(t)-Z(t-h_n)\right|\right]$$
for $h_n=t-\frac{\lfloor nt\rfloor}{n}\leq\frac{1}{n}$ and then applying Levy's modulus of continuity theorem.

Comment: By independence of the increments of $Z$, the supremum over $t$ in $[0,1]$ is the maximum of $n$ independent random variables distributed like $n^{-1/2}M_{1/n}$ where $M_s=\sup\limits_{0\leqslant t\leqslant s}|Z(t)|$ for every nonnegative $s$, hence each $M_{1/n}$ is distributed like $n^{-1/2}M_1$. Now you need some information on the tail of $\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}M_1^{(k)}$ for some independent copies $M_1^{(k)}$ of $M_1$. Any idea?